# Exception handling within enum instance

Tags: java, enums

How to handle exceptions within Enum instances in Java? I have an enum class as follows:

```
public enum TagEnum {

    EDIT_ACCESS("feature.edit", GlobalAccess.getEditStatus());

    private String key;
    private Boolean featureStatus;

    private TagEnum(String key, Boolean status) {
        this.key=key;
        this.featureStatus=status;
    }

}
```

In above scenario `getEditStatus()` method of `GlobalAccess` class throws Exception:

```
public static Boolean getEditStatus() throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Above `TagEnum` enum gave a compilation error because the enum instance cannot handle `GlobalAccess.getEditStatus()` method. Please guide me on how to pass java methods that throws exceptions, as an argument inside an Enum instance.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen if the method throws an exception?

Comment: @RooMan: I tried enclosing the contents of constructor within a try catch block, but still I get the same error. Even I tried throwing Exception from the enum constructor, but the issue still remains.

Comment: Wrap getEditStatus() in method that in case of exceptions returns default value.

Comment: If your issue was resolved, don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the grey tick.

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle an exception during class member declaration and declaring an `enum` in this sense is much the same as declaring a class.

You will have to move the `GlobalAccess.getEditStatus()` call into a block, constructor, or method to handle any exceptions that are thrown. As an example, you could move it into the constructor like so;

```
private TagEnum(String key) {
    this.key=key;
    try{
        this.featureStatus = GlobalAccess.getEditStatus();
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        // Handle the exception here. 
    }
}
```

Alternatively [Initialization Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) were created for more or less exactly this issue. To allow you handle logic, errors and exceptions during class(or enum) member declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a dedicated method which will be able to handle this exception, e.g.:

```java
public enum TagEnum {

    EDIT_ACCESS("feature.edit") {
        @Override
        protected Boolean initFeatureStatus() {
            try {
                return GlobalAccess.getEditStatus();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle it there
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    private String key;
    private Boolean featureStatus;

    private TagEnum(String key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.featureStatus = initFeatureStatus();
    }

    protected abstract Boolean initFeatureStatus();

}
```